# How to get last two record from the array of records inside for each loop in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, foreach

I m using laravel 5.4 I want to get last two images which is recently added i my it show all images added but how to check last two images inside for each and displayed in my view

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @if (!empty($product->name))
      <img src="{{ $product->front_img }}">
    @else
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/product-placeholder.jpg') }}">
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This is my code now how i get last two images ..Please help me out

Comment: What have you done for yourself to try and achieve your goal?

Comment: while select you can limit 2 and order by inserted_date desc

Comment: `$products = Product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(2)->paginate(5);'  The above code is correct @JYoThl

Comment: yeah correct @Karthiga

Comment: But it shows all items

Comment: Now working `$products = Product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(2)->get();'   changed to get() method

Comment: glad to help you @Karthiga . i posted answer below . if it's useful mark it with green tick . it's useful for future user reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `order by` and `limit`

```
$products = Product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(2)->get();
```